# VPN tunnel configuration

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, traffic

I use VPN tunnel to play games like League of legends or vidictus and I live in a college dorm and all gaming ports are blocked so I buy their services, but my browsers tend to eat my tunneling data.

So the question is can I make only certains programs to use tunnel or only certains not to use tunnel ?

I'm using win 7

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you saying that whne you browse the Internet, the pages fail to load as traffic is sent over the VPN? If this is so and assuming you use the native Windows 7 VPN, you can make a minor change to address this.  You simply need to use the local/default gateway for Internet traffic.

Right click on your VPN connection and click Properties.  Then click the networking tab.  Click Internet Protocol Version 4 and then click Properties and then click Advanced.  UNCHECK "Use defualt gateway on remote network"

Repeat for Internet Protocol Version 6 if you are using this protocol.

If you are using a VPN clinet like Cisco, there is usually a similar option.

Comment: no i mean i want that games like lol would use VPN tunnel (i use privat tunnel) and internet browser would use regular internet

Comment: My answer provides the solution you want.  Internet uses local gateway and VPN traffic remians as is.  You could haver issues if both local and VPN network are on the same subnet.  Easy fix there would be to change local subnet to a new network

Comment: I think that he may be using a third-party VPN server, so the game servers are not on the VPN provider's network; and if so he needs split tunneling.

Comment: Yes I use third-party server and software from privatepunel(dot)com based on Open Vpn

Answer (score 0):

If your VPN provider uses OpenVPN, try split tunneling. You could use it so that VPN is used only for traffic to the game servers' IP addresses, and everything else goes through the normal connections. I am not sure if split tunneling is possible by program, but it is definitely possible by IP addresses (of the game servers)

Comment: how i could do that split tunneling